# How to convert joined SQL data into json structure

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mongodb

I have the following query to get all the credits in a film called "I.D" --

```
SELECT title, platform, platform_id, type, credit, role
FROM main_iteminstance i inner join main_credit c on c.item_instance_id=i.id inner join main_creditperson p on c.person_id=p.id
WHERE i.id = 196365940 order by role_type_id, p.name
```

This gives me the following data:

```
+---------------------- main table --------------------+ +--------- joined table --------+
name        platform            platform_id     type            credit              role
I.D.        iTunes              1168241742      Movie           Geetanjali          Actor
I.D.        iTunes              1168241742      Movie           Murari Kumar        Actor
I.D.        iTunes              1168241742      Movie           Kamal K.M.          Director
I.D.        iTunes              1168241742      Movie           Geetanjali          Producer
```

I want to flatten this into an object with the least repetitive data to get it into a json object. For example, the below object would look like this:

```
{
    "platform": "iTunes",
    "platform_id": "1168241742",
    "type": "Movie",
    "name": "I.D.",
    "credits": {
        "actors": ["Geetanjali", "Murari Kumar"],
        "directors": ["Kamal K.M."],
        "producers": ["Geetanjali"]
    },
}
```

We can see above, that everything is 'flat' with the exception of the credits attribute. Is there any way to do a query where we basically 'json-ify' a joined table's data? What would the suggested approach be here. Basically, is there any way to go from sql to mongodb/json without using code in between?

Comment: Do it in the code that processes the query results and builds the array.

Comment: @Barmar is there a MongoDB or other documentation for converting normalized SWL data into common json structures? I know this depends on the actual data going in, but more like general principles and guidelines?

Comment: I don't know MongoDB. I would do this in a language like PHP.